# WiX installer VC++ redistributable in msi, Merge Modules do not exist

Tags: c#, visual-c++, wix, installation, redistributable

I am working on a WiX installer project for a windows application that requires VC++. I have a WiX msi installer that works fine on my Win10 environment with VC++ installed. But I would like to install VC++ on user computers along with my application installer if VC++ is not installed already on the user's computer

Following the [WiX documentation on VC++ with the installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html), I am not able to find 
 \Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules.

I do not know how to proceed further on the installer so that I can deploy it on machines without VC++

Comment: Did you also check \Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules ?

Comment: Yes, it does not exist there either. The closest I have to anything merge related is
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\
which only has a MergeMod.dll

Comment: Does the machine you are using to look for the merge modules have Visual Studio installed?

Comment: @CalumMacLeod Yes i'm using visual studio 2017

Comment: I have VS 2017 and the merge modules are there, and this is just a guess but they might be part of the Windows SDK because that's where redistributables commonly live.